# Power consumption of OpenCL code running on a NVIDIA GPU

Tags: power-supply, power, energy, gpu

I am trying to run OpenCL code for a MJPEG decoder on a Nvidia GPU (Tesla K20c). I asked questions on [other](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174433/opencl-implementations-of-iqzz-and-idct-for-mjpeg) stack exchange websites about implementing the decoder on the GPU and I am now trying to calculate the power consumption of each individual OpenCL kernel running on the Tesla K20c. 
*(I have translated 4 sequential C functions namely iqzz, IDCT, upsampling and color conversion into OpenCL kernels).*

I have been using `nvidia-smi` to check the power being drawn by the GPU when I am running my OpenCL code. The idle power consumption of K20c is 17 W when no code is being run.

[image]

I used the following method to examine the power of every individual kernel:

*In order to calculate the power consumption of a particular OpenCL kernel, I have been commenting out the remaining OpenCL kernels and letting their equivalent C versions run in their place. I have been doing this to let the code run correctly. Hence, when I want to run another OpenCL kernel, I activate (uncomment) the single-threaded C versions of the other kernels.*

Every single kernel whose power I wanted to examine in the above fashion drew power in the range of approximately 49 W to 55 W. The kernel for the function Upsampling consumed the most amount of power (55 W).

[image]

Moreover, I believe that if I run all the OpenCL kernels at once on the GPU, the total power consumption value should be a sum of the values I got when I ran every kernel individually. **Instead, the total power consumption when I ran all kernels at once came out to be 54.83 W!** The power consumption is even lower than the power consumed by the kernel for Upsampling.

***Do you have any suggestions for correctly calculating the power consumed by every kernel in my OpenCL code?*** Most research papers (like [this](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1987816.1987826) one) mention fancy techniques such as attaching probes to the PCI bus, the CPU and the GPU. However, I have a closed [system](https://www.cmc.ca/en/WhatWeOffer/Prototyping/HighPerformance/HPP.aspx) and I cannot use physical means to measure power.

**ADDITION:**

The utilization percentage of the GPU reached 98 % when I once added `printf` statements to one of my kernels.

[image]

Comment: 55 compared to 54.83 sounds like measurement error to me. Why is it unreasonable that the full GPU implementation consumes 54.83W? The K20C has 2496 cores. If you run one kernel, that one kernel will run on all cores. Run two kernels, and they'll share those 2496 cores. Either way only 2496 cores are powered at any given time. To verify your measurement technique, dispatch kernels with different numbers of threads (starting << core count of gpu), and see how it increases.
There will be a slight difference between kernels due to memory bandwidth, but at some point you will saturate the gpu.

Comment: @sebf I understand that the GPU can be saturated (refer to the addition I made to the question). I don't understand what you mean by _55 compared to 54.83 sounds like measurement error to me._

Comment: @sebf The power consumption that `nvidia-smi` probably includes power consumed by other surrounding components (bus, rails and so on). How can I calculate the **kernel's** power consumption?

Comment: I mean the 170mW difference may not mean that Upsampling alone consumes more power than all the kernels, but rather each time you measure it the measurements vary by more than 170mW. You could try running your kernels will different thread counts, starting from 1, plot them, and find the piecewise linear region (if one exists) and the gradient could approximate the power consumption of just one kernel invocation.

Answer (score 0):

`nvidia-smi` is returning power consumption information for the entire GPU, which I think will not be able to give you the granularity you want.

Power consumption for an "individual kernel" doesn't make much sense in that context; the GPU will be on and consuming *some* amount of power, regardless of what you're running on it. (This number should be your baseline for power consumption.)

- The 54.83W number you quoted implies that your kernel is consuming *less* power that upsampling, which makes sense, since upsampling is a very costly operation and would easily burn 170 mW more power.

(The 17W idle measurement is misleading, because the chipset is likely in some ACPI suspend state, where parts of the chip are entirely turned off, permitting "abnormally" low power consumption, which you could never reach with any kind of kernel running.)

Comment: 54.83 W is the power consumption I get when I run **ALL** the kernels on the GPU (**including** upsampling).